# Split map into two lists

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have an `Map<String,Integer>` and it's sorted by value like this:

```
set = map.entrySet();
list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer»(set);
Collections.sort( list, (o1, o2) -> (o2.getValue()).compareTo( o1.getValue() ));
```

I already have a sorted integer list from that map:

```
word_used = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values() 
.stream() 
.sorted() 
.collect(Collectors.toList())); 
Collections.reverse(word_used);
```

But how I can get a String list, which will be sorted equal to Map (by value)?

I mean if I have a map with items:

```
map.put("eggs",1500); 
map.put("echo",150); 
map.put("foo",320); 
map.put("smt",50);
```

and sort it like:

```
eggs : 1500 
foo : 320 
echo : 150 
smt : 50
```

I need to get 2 lists:

```
eggs 
foo 
echo 
smt
```

and

```
1500 
320 
150 
50
```

Comment: Would
`word_list = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet()
.stream()
.sorted()
.collect(Collectors.toList()));`
work ?

Comment: Note that it's misleading to say that the `Map` is sorted.  Constructing and sorting a `List` of the `Map`'s entries has no effect on the iteration order of that `Map`'s collection views.  You have only a sorted `List` -- which nevertheless can be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add projection to your streams using `map()`, like this:

```
List<String> word_used = map.entrySet() 
        .stream() 
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String,Integer>::getValue).reversed())
        .map(Map.Entry<String,Integer>::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Integer> ints_used = map.entrySet() 
        .stream() 
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String,Integer>::getValue).reversed())
        .map(Map.Entry<String,Integer>::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[Demo 1](http://ideone.com/H82H2e)

Note that this approach sorts twice. You can capture the entries once, and then project from that temporary list, like this:

```
List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> sortedList = map
        .entrySet() 
        .stream() 
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String,Integer>::getValue).reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> word_used = sortedList
        .stream()
        .map(Map.Entry<String,Integer>::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Integer> ints_used = sortedList
        .stream()
        .map(Map.Entry<String,Integer>::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[Demo 2](http://ideone.com/9UnJdu)

Answer (score 2):

You already have a `List` (referenced by variable `list`) of the map `Entry`s, sorted by value into the order you describe.  You can just construct new, separate `List`s of the keys and values from those objects.  The non-stream version of that might be:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : list) {
    words.add(entry.getKey());
    values.add(entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One might sort and iterate only once using this method:

```
    List<String> word_used = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> ints_used = map.entrySet().stream() 
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String,Integer>::getValue).reversed())
        .peek(e -> word_used.add(e.getKey()))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TreeMap with a comparator that compares values rather than keys, and then just call keys() and values() on that.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html